# Using WebStorm for Razor Syntax MVC

Tags: javascript, ide, asp.net-mvc

I am building a lot of client-side heavy SPA-like apps with VS2010 and MVC3/4.  VS2010 Javascript/HTML/CSS editing (mostly javascript) is interminably slow and sluggish.  I'd love to use something like JetBrains' WebStorm to edit my .CSHTML files (with embedded javascript, etc. because I am using RAzor to pop in URL names, etc.)

WebStorm seems to have all of the things I want.. better language recognition ("intellisense") and the ability to integrate additional outside libraries into this (I'm using Kendo), etc.

Is this possible?  How do you get WebStorm to recognize the @"" invoked Razor language inserts?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps [Microsoft's WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) would better suited? Or Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition for Web.

Comment: Try Rider. I love it. https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webstorm is pretty server side agnostic. I would think that JetBrain would be silly to enter the ASP.NET space with an IDE at this point. You can see their other offerings with IntelliJ and RubyMine, PhpStorm, PyCharm - all avoiding ASP.NET and MVC.

They've got Resharper too which is a great VS add on.

My advice, get a faster computer or even a solid state hard drive. Javascript completion on my machine isn't slow at all.

Are you following the rules for including other libraries? That's also supported in VS10 and 12...

Answer (score 9):

I am getting HTML and JavaScript autocompletion for *.cshtml files in WebStorm like this:

[image: Autocompletion in cshtml]

All I did was to register '*.cshtml' as html files under Settings | Editor | File Types
See: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/file-types.html

Comment: Great, adding *.cshtml as a pattern for HTML file types works perfectly.